# Web3: How to get the maxTransactionAmount for a token in python?

Tags: ethereum, cryptocurrency, web3py, binance-smart-chain

I'm currently working on code where I want to be able to buy what is max allowed to buy for the specific token.

In the smart contract, they sometimes implements a max transaction, i.e: 1% Max buy.

How can my code detect it in a smart contract and use it as a buy parameter in the function `contract.functions.swapExactETHForTokens()`? I imagine it would be something like,

```
maxTokens = token_contract.functions.maxAllowedTransactions
```

then, I can use maxTokens as a parameter in the swapExactETH. function.
I have tried googling around but I haven't encountered anything similar.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about uniswap v3/v2. There is no "max amount". The percentage you are referring to is the slippage amount which is represented as the variable `amountOutMin` in the `swapExactETHForTokens` function. This parameter is the minimum amount that you are willing to receive for x amount of ETH.

If you don't care about slippage then you can set `amountOutMin` to be equal to 0. You will likely get frontrun by MEV bots if you do this though.

The true maximum amount of a token that you can buy is the total amount of the tokens in the pool that you are swapping in. If a pool has 50 Buttcoins and 30 Dog coins, then you can buy a maximum of 30 dog coins for an infinite amount of Buttcoins. Based on the swap formula of:

```
buttcoin amount = 50 Butt / (30 Dog - 30 Dog) = infinity
```

Comment: there is a `maxTxAmount` defined by the dev himself. For example you could buy a max of 10k tokens, this is done to prevent having whales